# I need to change color when an element is clicked and at the same time save the element value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, event-handling

I have a list of rooms names in a `<Panel value="room01">`. When clicked I need to save the value(which is in the attribute) to an array and change the color to green. On the other hand I also need to be able to undo the selection, meaning, the value needs to be deleted from the array and the color has to go back to default. How would I achieve this in JS/React?

With the below function, I can get the value to the element

```
    onSelectRooms = (e) => {
        const selectedRooms = e.target.getAttribute("value");
    }
```

````
export default class ExportReportRoomSelectionModal extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            rooms: roomOrder,
            selectedRooms: [],

        };
        this.onSelectRooms = this.onSelectRoom.bind(this);
    }

    onSelectRooms = (e) => {
        const selectedRooms = e.target.getAttribute("value");
    } 

    render() {


        return (
            <Modal>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>TItle</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <p>Number of rooms: {this.state.rooms.length}</p>
                    <p>Rooms:</p>

                    <Grid fluid={true}> 
                        <Row className="show-grid">
                            { this.state.rooms.map((name, i ) => 
                                <Col key={i} xs={2} md={2}>
                                    <Panel onClick={this.onSelectRooms}>  
                                        <Panel.Heading value={name}> 
                                            {name}                               
                                        </Panel.Heading>
                                    </Panel> 
                                </Col>
                            )}
                        </Row>
                    </Grid>

                </Modal.Body>
            </Modal>);
    }
}```
````

Comment: First off, don't read the value of the attribute from the DOM. Doing so is an extremely un-React thing to do. The name of the panel is already stored in React state, so you should just read it from there. Can you post the code where `onSelectRooms` lives? Is that in a parent component or a child or what? What does `handleClick` do?

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. `onSelectRooms` function lives in same component - `ExportReportRoomSelectionModal` I have edited and added above. Also handle click doesn't do anything I've edited that bit aswell.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using name props instead of getting the value from event handler is a better approach.

```
    <Panel onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, name)}>
```

2. handleClick logic, toggling the panel

```
    handleClick(name, e) {
        if (this.state.selectedRooms.includes(name)) {
             // remove from array
             const newSelectedRooms = this.state.selectedRooms.filter(e => e !=== name);
             this.setState({selectedRooms: newSelectedRooms}):
        } else {
             // add to array
             this.setState(prevState => {selectedRooms: [..prevState.selectedRooms, name]});
        }
```

3. If you want to change color dynamically, you should do it based on state. Let's assume you have classname that change the color to green.

```
    <Panel
        onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, name)}
        className={this.state.selectedRooms.includes[name] ? 'green' : ''}
    >
```

Comment: `this.setState(prevState => {selectedRooms: [..prevState.selectedRooms, name]});` doesn't seem to add the value to the selectedRooms array in state on click.

Comment: I think that's a code error, you can't implicitly return an object from an arrow function like that because it confuses the interpreter. Try `this.setState(prevState => {return {selectedRooms: [..prevState.selectedRooms, name]}});`

Comment: Or `this.setState(prevState => ({selectedRooms: [..prevState.selectedRooms, name]}));`